# How to ask user to grant RECORD_AUDIO permission to googlequicksearchbox from my app

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm developing an app that uses [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer). This requires the RECORD_AUDIO permission and thus I ask for it to the user. So far, so good.

However, I recently learned that SpeechRecognizer relies on the Google app (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) and, if this app lacks RECORD_AUDIO permission, the speech recognition does not work at all (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006238/3519813)).

In other words, my app requires the RECORD_AUDIO permission granted for itself and also for the googlequicksearchbox app.

How can I ask the user to grant the RECORD_AUDIO permission for googlequicksearchbox? I mean, **how to programmatically open the RECORD_AUDIO permission dialog for googlequicksearchbox?**

I already know that I can tell the user to browse through the menus (Settings -> Apps -> Google -> Permissions -> Microphone) but I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions to ask permission before accessing `SpeechRecognizer`

Comment: thanks for the pointer @Priyankagb, but unfortunately this library only seems to deal with the permissions of the same app.